# Couldn't edit the VM instance created

Tags: google-compute-engine

So I used to be able to edit the resource of a instance (# of cpus, RAM, # of GPUs etc.) I have been unable to do so since days ago. I'm getting the following error when finishing my edit, e.g. simply select to decrease or increase RAM via console.

```
Invalid value for field 'resource.sourceMachineImage': ''. Updating 'sourceMachineImage' is not supported.
```

I don't think there's change in, e.g. role or anything. What could I be missing here?
Thanks!

Comment: Exactly what procedure are you doing?

Comment: Same question on the thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66533413

Answer (score 0):

This error could be related to the machine type of the instance, I would suggest you to [change it](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance#changing_a_machine_type) and try again. I would also be helpful to add the process that you are following and all the information that you could gather from the instance.

Have a nice day!